# How do I remove an extra overlay layer on p element?

Tags: css, hover, overlay

I have a rollover image that adds an overlay when the user hovers.
I also display "Shop Now" text on top of the image when the user hovers over the image. 
My problem is that when the user hovers over the image, an overlay is added to the div containing the image and also the "Show Now" text.
That makes the "Shop Now" text look darker since it has two overlays.
How do I remove the extra layer on the "Shop Now" text?

This is my css:

```
.banner-box{
    width:313px;
    height:313px;

}

/*banner overlay*/


div.homepage-popular-categories {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

div.homepage-popular-categories:hover p {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

div.homepage-popular-categories p:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

div.homepage-popular-categories p {
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: #eeeeec;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.5s;
    opacity: 1;
}




div.homepage-popular-categories:hover .shop-now-button {
    visibility:visible;


}
div.homepage-popular-categories .shop-now-button {
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 28%;
    bottom: 0;
    max-height: 40px;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top:20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-width: 125px;
    font-size:1em;
    padding-top:5px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    visibility:hidden;
}

/*end banner overlay*/
```

This is my html

```
<a href="#">
  <div id="ipad-width1" class="grid12-4 banner strov-3-banners shop-by-goal banner-box homepage-popular-categories ">
    <p>SHOP BY GOAL</p>
    <p class="shop-now-button">Shop Now</p>
  </div>
</a>
<a href="#">
  <div class="grid12-4 banner strov-3-banners trending banner-box homepage-popular-categories ">
    <p>TRENDING</p>
    <p class="shop-now-button">Shop Now</p>
  </div>
</a>
<a href="#">
  <div id="ipad-width3" class="grid12-4 banner strov-3-banners new-arrivals banner-box homepage-popular-categories ">
    <p>NEW ARRIVALS</p>
<p class="shop-now-button">Shop Now</p>
  </div>
</a>
```

Here's my fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/a75wbabp/

The oval with the Shop Now text should look like this
[image]

Comment: Why the JavaScript tag?

Comment: @j08691 My fault i changed it to css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this CSS right after the `:hover` rules:

```
div.homepage-popular-categories:hover .shop-now-button {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

The problem is the button inherits the background color of the container for some weird reason. This will ensure it stays transparent.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to the `.shop-now-button` on hover

```
background: transparent;
```

Check the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Pranesh456/3uszm3o7/1/